# Leaflet: Get inner-most layer on mouse click and mouse hover on intersecting rectangles

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I am trying to display a set of rectangles on a map. I am able to draw all of them using:

```
var rec = L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1})
                .bindTooltip('Z1', { sticky: true}).addTo(map);
```

However, when I hover over the rectangles, the tooltip is shown only for the outer-most rectangle. Also, in click event, only the outer-most rectangle is selected.
(Note that larger rectangles can be layered over smaller ones)

Given this situation - how do I show the tooltip correctly and retreive the proper layer on click event?

Stackblitz : [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4bbt7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `Z2` rectangle lies behind the `Z1` (`Z1` contains `Z2`).

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
   return L.bounds(a.bounds).contains(b.bounds) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Here I sorted the bounds using [`contains`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#bounds-contains) method

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i8wfyp)

Comment: I am reading the rectangle bounds from database and have an extra "priority" column and rendering rectangles based on this value. But this is a good client side solution. I will mark it as the answer. Thank you!